# Redraw in parent window in child window's onPaint in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to implement something like this in mfc:

A parent window that contains a few child windows. I want some horizontal and vertical grid lines to appear around a child window when ever the window is being dragged anywhere inside the parent. For that, I am tracking movement in my     OnPaint() handler for the child and accessing the parent and drawing these grid lines around the child. But its not behaving the way I want it to.

My guess is that the child's     OnPaint() only updates the child's drawing region, so even if I do access the parent's DC, I cant draw anything on it unless it's being redrawn?

Can anybody suggest a neater method of achieving above functionality? What am I doing wrong? I need everything to happen in the child's     OnPaint()

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just pass data to the parent window and call its Invalidate function. Then it would paint the grid lines in its own OnPaint.

Or you could paint directly on the parent window from the child, but use the parent's GetDC function instead of using the child's DC.

Comment: If I call the parent's invalidate function, would it draw all the child windows and the rest of the content in it as well? I just need the grid lines around the child when ever the child is being dragged on the screen.

Thats what I was trying originally, getting the parent's DC in the child's OnPaint and drawing these grid lines. This should technically work right? but nothing was drawn in my case. If i drag randomly on the screen causing allot of OnPaint calls, then I see a few overlapped lines.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to draw a semi-transparent grid window using `UpdateLayeredWindow` on top of the parent client area while you arrange the child window on top of it. The grid window can then be destroy after the arrangement is done. In this way, there will be minimum changes required to the existing display code.